# What does the Trait "He's a Jonah, that one" mean?

Tags: burning-wheel, traits

The Burning Wheel has a character Trait called "He's a Jonah, that one" (BWG p.329). Like many character Traits in BW it has no further description. So what is the trait supposed to mean?

A general online search yielded either [a cool dude](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Jonah) or [the biblical prophet Jonah / bringer of bad luck](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Jonah) for just the name Jonah and nothing for the whole phrase.

Comment: As a side note, I would not consider Urban Dictionary to be reliable by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: @JoelHarmon I think it is useful to get a general idea about some more obscure slang. But only if there are many similar answers. And of course even then it is to be taken with a truckload of salt. That's why I quickly disregarded the results from UD in my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is straightforward and you found it yourself: it means a person who brings bad luck (usually to a ship).  It comes from the biblical story and is an old sailor expression/superstition.

The flowery title of the trait is just a dialog example of how a NPC sailor might accuse someone of being bad luck in-game.

There's a famous movie scene about a sailor constantly accused of being a Jonah.  Spoiler alert if you have never watched 
[Master & Commander](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbutW_ouy60).

Answer (score 7):

A good idea with BW character Traits is to look, which Lifepaths have them as Lifepath Traits. The Lifepath Crazy Old Sailor has that Trait as a LP Trait alongside Superstitious and Metal Plate in the Skull (BWG p. 190). With that it is obvious that the Trait is referring to the second source more than the first. I see three plausible ways of interpreting it:

- Other people see the character as bad luck and say "He's a Jonah, that one" about him
- The character himself is prone to labeling random people as bringers of bad luck (plays of Superstitious)
- The character was literally swallowed up by a see monster and then spat back out (where do you think the plate in his skull come from).